# App crashes on hiding ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I have a `Button` which `calls` function `hide_bar()` when clicked.

```
public void hide_bar(View v){
        ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
        ab.hide();
    }
```

But instead of hiding the Action Bar it **crashes the app**.

How to fix this bug ?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.prateek.myapp, PID: 19919 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference
```

**UPDATE (Problem Fixed):**

I was not able  to use `getActionBar()` because my `manifest` file defined the **AppCompat theme** for which you have to use **getSupportActionBar()** .

After replacing Theme in manifest file to `Theme.Holo.Light` I was able to use `getActionBar()` method .

Comment: Can you post the logcat error

Comment: please post stacktrace.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.prateek.myapp, PID: 19919
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference

Comment: please show your whole class.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8EE9SCEX

Comment: Thanks, for your whole class, please have a look of my answer.

Comment: use getSupportActionBar();

Comment: Instead of editing your question to include your solution, please post it as an answer and accept it. The question should be *only* your question.

Comment: I wanna do that but someone put the question "on hold" and because of this it is not showing answer textarea to me :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are extending `ActionBarActivity` you need get actionBar by calling

```
actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
```

Comment: It worked dude but which class I should extend so that I can use 
 ActionBar ab= getActionBar();

Comment: If your app support from API level 3.0 (HoneyComb) and higher that time you can extend Activity and can use getActionBar();..

Comment: I tried it but even then my app crashes.

Comment: The same Exception (NullPointerException) mentioned above.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4012)

Comment: paste all whole `Activity` class.. give me a  link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82045/discussion-between-bharat-and-prateek-joshi).

Answer (score 1):

You need to know what's of action bar your application uses to call the correct method to get action bar.
Also your exception is NPE so you need check the value of variable before using it.

Please refer below code:

```
public void hide_bar(View v){
    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    if (ab != null)
      ab.hide();
    else {
      ab = getSupportActionBar();
      if (ab != null) ab.hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't  you think while he is extending `ActionBarActivity` here `ActionBar ab = getActionBar();` always will return `null`

Comment: I do not remember exactly but it's not hard to find the correct answer if you are sitting with a editor :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this,

```
ActionBar ab;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ab = getActionBar();
    }

    public void hide_bar(View v){
           ab.hide();
    }
```

Comment: don't you think `getActionBar` will return `null` if your class is extending `ActionBarActivity`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to call setSystemUiVisibilty() and set UI flags before you call hide().

The actual code snippet for hiding the action bar is this:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();  int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN; decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);  ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); actionBar.hide();
```

Taken from developer.android.com

Please refer https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html#41 for more details

Comment: user doesn't need to hide status bar.

Comment: you code always return null `actionBar` as he is extending `ActionBarActivity`

Comment: Yes Bharath, I saw the class just now. It wasn't mentioned at the time I answered. The question was very ambiguous and didn't have any proper details at the time, so this is all I could write.